# Highlight all keys that look like '&name=' in a text with grep console

Tags: regex, colors, grep

I am using grep console plugin in my development environment and I want to highlight parts of my console that look like '&name='. 
I tried with following regex: [&].*[=]

I want lines like this:

> lorem&variable=something{ipsum}&paramter="555"

to look like this

> lorem**&variable=**something{ipsum}**&paramter=**"555"

What would be the grep command to do that

Comment: `grep -Po '&.*?='` or `grep -o '&[^=]*='`

Comment: First one does the job. Thanks!